# How to typeset Japanese ascii art in latex?

Tags: listings, verbatim, japanese

I am thinking about creating a package, which provides an environment that uses MS PGothic to typeset some fancy Japanese ASCII art.
MS PGothic is the default font for Japanese ASCII art.

My thinking is to create a new verbatim environment.
But it seems that verbatim requires the font to be mono-spaced, meanwhile, MS PGothic is proportional, and the font has to be proportional to be able to typeset Japanese ASCII art.

I have tried to create some packages by pitching up the info I collected here and there.
One of them is like:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{jart}[2023/03/05 Japanese ASCII Art]

\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}

% Set the font to MS PGothic
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{msgothic.ttc}

% Set character width and line height
\fvset{fontsize=\small,xleftmargin=2em,}
\def\num{18}
\def\px{16}

% Define the "jart" environment
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{jart}{Verbatim}
{fontfamily=tt,numbers=none,framesep=0.5em,rulecolor=white,baselinestretch=\num/\px}
```

But it doesn't work.
I think there exists some rudimentary mistakes in my package that I failed to see.

I would really appreciate it if someone shed some light on this subject.
I have a copy of "Latex Companion 2ed", guidance on which chapter I need to read is welcomed.

Examples of proper typeset ASCII art can be seen here: https://aahub.org/
Thx in advance.

### -

- 
- 
- 
- 

**EDIT 1:** Thanks to Niranjan's answer, the question is almost solved.
I mentioned that the font used in Japanese ASCII art must be proportional. By "proportional" I mean each character have different width. To illustrate the problem of the existing wonderful answer, I would have to include some external image links.

This is my main Tex file used to typeset a sample ASCII art :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jart}
\begin{document}
First document. This is a simple example, with no 
extra parameters or packages included.


\begin{jart}
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＿＿＿＿＿＿
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　,､.- '''"´　　　　　　　　　 ｀ ' ‐ ､,
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　,､ ''"　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 　　 `' .､
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 ,､ '"　　　　　　　　　 .......................　　　　　　　　 ＼
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　／　　　　　　　..........::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::....... ...　　　ヽ
    　　　　　　　　　　　　／　　　　　　....:::::::::::::::;;::::::::::::::::;:::;､ｒ'" ＼:::::::::::::::::.....::..　　　ヽ
    .　　　　　　　　　　／　　　　　　..::::::::::::::::::::/　｀ヽ,:／ノ　　　　　＼ィ'ヽ:::::::::::::::..　　 ヽ
    .　　　　　　　　 ／　　　　　 ..:::::::::::::::::::;､:ィ'　　　　｀　 ヽ 　 　 　 　ヽ　 ＼:::::::::::::..　　 ',
    　　　　　　　 , '　　　　　　..:::::::::::::::;､r':／,'　　　 .....　　　　　　　　　　ヽ　　 ヽ::::::::::..　　',
    .　　　　　　, '　　　　　　..::::::::::;､ '" ／　,'　　／ ,､-ヽ　　　　　　　　　　',　　　 ヽ::::::::..　/
    　　　　　 /　　　　　　..::::::::／　 ／　　,'　　/／　　　ヽ.　　 ヽ　　　 ヽ　',　 　 　ヽ::::::::/
    　　　　 /　　　　　...::::::::／　 ／　　　 ; 　 /　　　　　　 ヽ　　ヽ　 ヽ　丶 ',　　　　ヽ／
    　　　 /　　　　 ..::::::::::::iﾞ　 ／　　　　 ,'　　i 　　 　 　　 　 ヽ　ヾ、　 ヽ　＼',　　　　',
    .　　 /　　　....:::::::::::::::::i..／　　　　,､ ,'　　 |　,.､----- ､,　　',　 ',.＼　 ヾ' ､ヽ　　　　',
    　　/　　 ..:::::::::::::::::::::／　　　,､ '"　,'　　　|´　　　　　　　 　 ',　 !. ‐ヽ　ヽ　ヾ ､　　　',
    　/　....::::::::::::::::::::::／　　,､ '".--､i /／!.　|　　　　　　　 　 　 ',　l 　　ヽ. ',､. ',　｀　、　',
    　 ＼::::::::::::::::::::／　,､ '"　/ ,r''''''|〃 　|　|,.|ｨ=＝＝ﾐ､　 　　　', |,　-ﾉ-､　 /‐!　　 | ＼ ',
    　　　｀'　､:.:／ ,､ '" |.　　│ ! /~|　　　l　',　　　　　　　　 　　 lﾉ=＝=ﾐ､ /l　|　 　 | 　 ＼
    　　　　,､ｒ'ィ"‐-:､;;;_|　　　ヽ ヽ、|　　　 i　',＼＼＼　 　 　　 　 　 　 　 { l　i　lヽ !
    　　　´　　　　　　　,'　　　 　＼　l　　　 .',、'､　　　　　　　,　 ＼＼＼!|　l 　! ' ,ヽ !
    　　　　　　　　　　/　　　　　　 ｀ l　　　　',ヽヽ　　　　 　 　 　 　　　　|!|　ヽ .| ',.ヽ!
    .　　　　　　　　　/　　　　　　　　 l　　　　 !　｀ヽ 　、＿.．-､＿,　　　/.ﾊ.　V　 ',
    　　　　　　　　 /　　　　　　　 ,､ -',　　　　',‐‐―┐　　 　 　 　 　 ／ /　　| 　　',
    　　　　　　　, '　　　　 ,､- '''´　　　',　　　　', 　 　|.　　　 　 　 ィ ´ 　/　 　 |ｰ-､ ',
    　　　　　 ／　　　　　 l　　　　　　　',　　　　',　　ﾄ＞ ‐ ＜´＿!　 　/　　　/　／　',
    　　　 ／　　　　　　　 ',　　　　　　　 ',　　　　', ├---ﾞﾆiﾞ､.,,,,,{　　/　 　 / ／ |＼　',
    　 ／　　　／　　　　　 ヽ　　　　　　　',　　　　',│　||　 || 　||ヽ　　　　 /　ﾄ,　|　 ヽ ヽ
    '"　　　 ／　　　　　　　　> 　 　 　　　 ',　　　　',ヽ. ||　 ||　 ||:}　 　 　 / 　 | l. l　 　ヽ　'
    
\end{jart}

\end{document}
```

The same art used in my tex file, if properly typeset, look like this:
[image: A proper typeset ASCII ART]

But using existing answer produce this:
[image]

You can see that the character is all there, but the proportion is wrong.
Some character is widened, pushing other characters to the right.

By inspecting the resulting PDF, it seems the width of each character is fixed to full-width and half-with.
I hope I clearly described the problem.

### -

- 
- 

EDIT 2:
Using other fonts works, like the `aahub` font provided here: https://fonts.aahub.org/

Comment: Please give a specific example that fails. With your code I get an error `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` due to the baselinestretch option. Without that option the environment works fine, including with Japanese characters

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Good and well-worked question :-)

Comment: https://velvetyne.fr/news/about-ascii-art-and-jgs-font/ will interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be a safer way of doing what you want:

```
\ProvidesPackage{jart}[2023/03/06 Japanese ASCII Art]
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\verbatimfont[%
  NFSSFamily       = {myverbatimfont}%
]{msgothic.ttc}
\fvset{fontsize=\small,xleftmargin=2em}
\def\jart@num{18}
\def\jart@px{16}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{jart}{Verbatim}{%
  fontfamily=myverbatimfont,%
  numbers=none,%
  framesep=0.5em,%
  rulecolor=white,%
  baselinestretch=\numexpr\jart@num/\jart@px\relax
}
```

1. I don't use the `\setmonofont` command as it globally changes the font used for `\verb`-type text. Instead I define a `\newfontfamily` and use it locally just for your environment.
2. Since this is supposed to be a package, it is always advisable to prefix the package-specific macros with the package-name, e.g., `\jartnum` instead of just `\num`. We always make the package-macros more and more specific for the end-users. Basically, it gives more freedom to them, since now anyone can use `\def\num{some-interesting-definition}` in their documents and this wouldn't change anything from `jart` since we specifically have `\jartnum`.
3. About the `@` sign: In 'internal' macros, i.e., the macros only required by the package, we also add the '@' sign in the macro somewhere, conventionally after the package-name prefix. So instead of `\jartnum` I have used `\jart@num`. Now even if some user tries to redefine `\jart@num` in their code, LaTeX won't accept it. They will have to use the special command `\makeatletter` in order to redefine it. This basically makes your code safer for both the package as well as the end user and the coding becomes more free.
4. You can't do math on-the-fly in LaTeX unlike in some programming languages. You have to initiate calculations, for which LaTeX has `\numexpr`. We define values with internal macros and then apply calculations on them with `\numexpr` like seen in the code.
5. You don't need the `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}` line anymore these days.

PS: Not related to your code, but since you are planning to release a package, try to use a font which is distributed with TeX Live. Your `msgothic.ttc` is not. Also it's not free (as in freedom). Look for a free alternative and use it.

Comment: \numexpr will round division result to integer. Try `\fpeval`.

Comment: @user202729 can you please explain more? Also feel free to edit the code and the explanation. I haven't ever used `\fpeval` so I don't know it's specifications.

Comment: Thank you, Niranjan, your code throws no error, and your explanation cleared things up for me. After I test it, I can get a readable PDF and all the characters are there, but it seems that the characters only get two widths, like only Half-width and Full-width. This causes some characters to get pushed further to the right and break the ASCII art. Is this fixable?

Comment: @LNseyJt2X-24UJ4r7KTL I am glad that my answer was at least helpful to solve some part of your problem. I don't understand the problem you mentioned, I guess a minimal example would help, but since it is a new problem, I would advise asking a new question. You can refer to this answer in your new question. Also, don't consider this to be the final version. User202729 has spotted some problem and I myself am waiting for their response/edit.

Comment: I think this is still in the scope of this question. I have edited the question and included some graphics to illustrate the "width" problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: @LNseyJt2X-24UJ4r7KTL Which font do you **want** TeX to use exactly? Of course the `tt` font will not be proportional.

Comment: @user202729 thanks for the edit, I will just add a `%` at the end-of-line for consistency ;-)

Comment: @LNseyJt2X-24UJ4r7KTL Actually I can't reproduce the problem, it's most likely because the font is configured to be fixed at half width/full width. If I use Latin Modern font (family lmr, which is a proportional font) in verbatim environment, then the proportional width works correctly.

Comment: @user202729 It seems that using `fpeval` causes errors like `Missing number, treated as zero.` and `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

Comment: @LNseyJt2X-24UJ4r7KTL not for me, make sure you have used the same code in the sty file.

Comment: @user202729 sorry, i am kinda new to Latex, what do you mean by `tt` font?
I will try other font.

Comment: Also, the `\fpeval` command is usable directly in the code after the 2022-06-01 release, so if your LaTeX system is older, you need to use `\RequirePackage{xfp}`.

Comment: @Niranjan Thx, `\RequirePackage{xfp}` saved it.

Comment: @user202729
After testing with other capable fonts, the problem is solved. I tried fonts provided by https://fonts.aahub.org/ and it typeset the art properly. Thank you for your effort and time on this question.
(Though I don't understand why MS PGothic would not produce proper art, it is should be the font for those arts.)

Comment: @LNseyJt2X-24UJ4r7KTL after user202729's edit I realized that unit was actually not needed. So the error you were getting was because of uninitiated math. Now we can in fact use `\def`s and the code will be smaller and easier. This way we can go back to `\numexpr` and avoid one dependency, `\RequirePackage{xfp}`. I will make the changes.