# style of self-defined verbatim environement changed after using xeCJK

Tags: xetex, verbatim, xecjk

So, in [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678295/how-to-typeset-japanese-ascii-art-in-latex) I asked how to create a verbatim environment with specified font, height and width, to typeset Japanese ASCII art.
And they helped me out with that, now I have a proper package I can use to do that.
It looks like this:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{jart}[2023/03/05 Japanese ASCII Art]
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
\RequirePackage{xfp}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\verbatimfont[%
  NFSSFamily       = {myverbatimfont}%
]{aahub.ttf}

\fvset{fontsize=\small,xleftmargin=2em}

\newdimen\jart@num
\jart@num=16pt\relax

\newdimen\jart@px
\jart@px=16pt\relax

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{jart}{Verbatim}{%
  fontfamily=myverbatimfont,%
  numbers=none,%
  framesep=0.5em,%
  rulecolor=white,%
  baselinestretch=\fpeval{\jart@num/\jart@px}%
}
```

`aahub.ttf` is a font developed to do this kind of typesetting by:https://font.aahub.org/

But, you know, it is created to typeset Japanese ASCII art. It would be good if i can actually type some CJK characters in the main body of the Document.

I am using `XeLatex`, so I would just add `\usepackage{xeCJK}` to the file.
But the resulting ASCII art is broken.
Without `\usepackage{xeCJK}` it works fine.

EXAMPLE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jart}
% \usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
This is a minial working example of typesetting Japanese ASCII art.


\begin{jart}
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　＿＿＿＿＿＿
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　,､.- '''"´　　　　　　　　　 ｀ ' ‐ ､,
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　,､ ''"　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 　　 `' .､
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 ,､ '"　　　　　　　　　 .......................　　　　　　　　 ＼
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　／　　　　　　　..........::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::....... ...　　　ヽ
　　　　　　　　　　　　／　　　　　　....:::::::::::::::;;::::::::::::::::;:::;､ｒ'" ＼:::::::::::::::::.....::..　　　ヽ
.　　　　　　　　　　／　　　　　　..::::::::::::::::::::/　｀ヽ,:／ノ　　　　　＼ィ'ヽ:::::::::::::::..　　 ヽ
.　　　　　　　　 ／　　　　　 ..:::::::::::::::::::;､:ィ'　　　　｀　 ヽ 　 　 　 　ヽ　 ＼:::::::::::::..　　 ',
　　　　　　　 , '　　　　　　..:::::::::::::::;､r':／,'　　　 .....　　　　　　　　　　ヽ　　 ヽ::::::::::..　　',
.　　　　　　, '　　　　　　..::::::::::;､ '" ／　,'　　／ ,､-ヽ　　　　　　　　　　',　　　 ヽ::::::::..　/
　　　　　 /　　　　　　..::::::::／　 ／　　,'　　/／　　　ヽ.　　 ヽ　　　 ヽ　',　 　 　ヽ::::::::/
　　　　 /　　　　　...::::::::／　 ／　　　 ; 　 /　　　　　　 ヽ　　ヽ　 ヽ　丶 ',　　　　ヽ／
　　　 /　　　　 ..::::::::::::iﾞ　 ／　　　　 ,'　　i 　　 　 　　 　 ヽ　ヾ、　 ヽ　＼',　　　　',
.　　 /　　　....:::::::::::::::::i..／　　　　,､ ,'　　 |　,.､----- ､,　　',　 ',.＼　 ヾ' ､ヽ　　　　',
　　/　　 ..:::::::::::::::::::::／　　　,､ '"　,'　　　|´　　　　　　　 　 ',　 !. ‐ヽ　ヽ　ヾ ､　　　',
　/　....::::::::::::::::::::::／　　,､ '".--､i /／!.　|　　　　　　　 　 　 ',　l 　　ヽ. ',､. ',　｀　、　',
　 ＼::::::::::::::::::::／　,､ '"　/ ,r''''''|〃 　|　|,.|ｨ=＝＝ﾐ､　 　　　', |,　-ﾉ-､　 /‐!　　 | ＼ ',
　　　｀'　､:.:／ ,､ '" |.　　│ ! /~|　　　l　',　　　　　　　　 　　 lﾉ=＝=ﾐ､ /l　|　 　 | 　 ＼
　　　　,､ｒ'ィ"‐-:､;;;_|　　　ヽ ヽ、|　　　 i　',＼＼＼　 　 　　 　 　 　 　 { l　i　lヽ !
　　　´　　　　　　　,'　　　 　＼　l　　　 .',、'､　　　　　　　,　 ＼＼＼!|　l 　! ' ,ヽ !
　　　　　　　　　　/　　　　　　 ｀ l　　　　',ヽヽ　　　　 　 　 　 　　　　|!|　ヽ .| ',.ヽ!
.　　　　　　　　　/　　　　　　　　 l　　　　 !　｀ヽ 　、＿.．-､＿,　　　/.ﾊ.　V　 ',
　　　　　　　　 /　　　　　　　 ,､ -',　　　　',‐‐―┐　　 　 　 　 　 ／ /　　| 　　',
　　　　　　　, '　　　　 ,､- '''´　　　',　　　　', 　 　|.　　　 　 　 ィ ´ 　/　 　 |ｰ-､ ',
　　　　　 ／　　　　　 l　　　　　　　',　　　　',　　ﾄ＞ ‐ ＜´＿!　 　/　　　/　／　',
　　　 ／　　　　　　　 ',　　　　　　　 ',　　　　', ├---ﾞﾆiﾞ､.,,,,,{　　/　 　 / ／ |＼　',
　 ／　　　／　　　　　 ヽ　　　　　　　',　　　　',│　||　 || 　||ヽ　　　　 /　ﾄ,　|　 ヽ ヽ
'"　　　 ／　　　　　　　　> 　 　 　　　 ',　　　　',ヽ. ||　 ||　 ||:}　 　 　 / 　 | l. l　 　ヽ　'

\end{jart}

\end{document}
```

No `xeCJK`:

[image: no xeCJK result]

With `xeCJK`:

[image: with xeCJK]

I am not sure why this has happened.
Where should I be looking at to solve this issue?
Thx in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASCII art contains characters that are supported to use CJK font. Such as `U+FF64` `U+30FD`. If your CJK font does not have these glyphs, it cannot print properly. In the meantime, `xeCJK` would insert some spaces between CJK characters and others. You are not willing to keep them.

You can turn off the modification made by `xeCJK`, by setting `\xeCJKsetup{xeCJKactive=false}`. Or you can remove those spaces and change the CJK font.

```tex
% In jart.sty, choose one of them, I prefer the first one
\newcommand{\turnoffxecjk}{\xeCJKsetup{xeCJKactive=false}}
% \newcommand{\turnoffxecjk}{\xeCJKsetup{CJKglue=,CJKecglue=,}\CJKfontspec{aahub.ttf}}
% and
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{jart}{Verbatim}{%
  formatcom=\turnoffxecjk,%
  fontfamily=myverbatimfont,%
  numbers=none,%
  framesep=0.5em,%
  rulecolor=white,%
  baselinestretch=\fpeval{\jart@num/\jart@px}%
}
```